# The method addHandler(String, server) is undefined for the type WebServer

Tags: java, apache, xml-rpc

If I run this server program I got an above error. How should I clear this?

```
public class server {

    public static void main(String args[]){      try {

        System.out.println("Attempting to start XML-RPC Server...");

        WebServer server = new WebServer(80);
        (server).addHandler("sample", new server());
        server.start();

        System.out.println("Started successfully.");
        System.out.println("Accepting requests. (Halt program to stop.)");

     } catch (Exception exception){
        System.err.println("server: " + exception);
     }

    }

}
```

Comment: include the imports for your class so that we know what WebServer class you are using.

Answer (score 0):

What the error basically means is that the class `WebServer` doesnt have the relevant method in its definition.
What is the full qualified name of the WebServer class?
Assuming it is `org.apache.xmlrpc.webserver.WebServer`, you can look at the [docs](https://ws.apache.org/xmlrpc/apidocs/org/apache/xmlrpc/webserver/WebServer.html) to see that it has no `addHandler()` method.

There is another problem with your code, you cannot call new on an object.

```
(server).addHandler("sample", new server());
```

Here `server` is an object not a class, and hence `new server()` is going cause you issues.

Answer (score 0):

in **xmlrpc-2.0.1** JAR addHandler(java.lang.String name, java.lang.Object target) method belongs to a class WebServer of xmlrpc and later on this method is removed. try using mentioned jar.

download from here http://archive.apache.org/dist/ws/xmlrpc/binaries

You can also find the API document at given link.
https://ws.apache.org/xmlrpc/xmlrpc2/apidocs/org/apache/xmlrpc/WebServer.html